# Как нарисовать с elif дом на turtle?

Tags: python, turtle

[image: lдом]

помогите пж нарисовать дом в turtle

Вот мой код:

```py
import turtle

turtle.shape("turtle")
turtle.color("black")
turtle.speed(1)
turtle.forward(164)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(140)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(164)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(140)
turtle.left(180)
turtle.forward(140)
turtle.right(55)
turtle.forward(100)
turtle.right(69)
turtle.forward(100)
turtle.right(56.5)
turtle.forward(140)
turtle.right(88)
turtle.forward(60)
turtle.right(92)
turtle.forward(90)
turtle.left(92)
turtle.forward(40)
turtle.left(88)
turtle.forward(90)
```

Comment: покажите код, как вы сами попытались решить эту задачу, и где у вас возникли трудности

Comment: приложите в сам вопрос с форматированием кода

Comment: Зачем здесь **elif**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял что ваш код рисует лишние линии, и из-за этого появляются  более жирные линии, то вам надо поставить дополнительные вызовы функций `up` и `down` (они поднимают и опускают перо):

```py
import turtle

turtle.shape("turtle")
turtle.color("black")
turtle.speed(1)
turtle.forward(164)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(140)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(164)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(140)
turtle.left(180)
turtle.up()  # <--
turtle.forward(140)
turtle.right(55)
turtle.down()  # <--
turtle.forward(100)
turtle.right(69)
turtle.forward(100)
turtle.right(56.5)
turtle.up()  # <--
turtle.forward(140)
turtle.right(88)
turtle.forward(60)
turtle.right(92)
turtle.down()  # <--
turtle.forward(90)
turtle.left(92)
turtle.forward(40)
turtle.left(88)
turtle.forward(90)
```